Unable to Authenticate to Private Terraform Module Registry with MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1 - Checkov
I am encountering an issue with the Microsoft Security DevOps task (microsoftsecuritydevops@1) when trying to authenticate to our private Terraform module registry using the Checkov. Although Checkov supports authentication via the TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN environment variable, this method does not seem to work within the microsoftsecuritydevops@1 task.
Could you please provide guidance on how to successfully authenticate to a private module registry while using Checkov in this context?
I have tried:
- task: MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1 
displayName: 'Checkov Policy Scanner' 
inputs:     
    command: run 
    policy: azuredevops 
    tools: checkov 
    break: true 
    publish: true 
    artifactName: CodeAnalysisLogs 
env: 
    TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN: $(TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN) 
    TF_HOST_NAME: $(TF_HOST_NAME) 
    GDN_CHECKOV_FRAMEWORK: "terraform" 
    GDN_CHECKOV_DOWNLOADEXTERNALMODULES: "true"

and also tried:
- task: MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1 
displayName: 'Checkov Policy Scanner' 
inputs:     
    command: run 
    policy: azuredevops 
    tools: checkov 
    break: true 
    publish: true 
    artifactName: CodeAnalysisLogs 
env: 
    GDN_CHECKOV_TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN: $(TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN) 
    GDN_CHECKOV_TF_HOST_NAME: $(TF_HOST_NAME) 
    GDN_CHECKOV_FRAMEWORK: "terraform" 
    GDN_CHECKOV_DOWNLOADEXTERNALMODULES: "true"

But nothing seems to work. If Checkov is replacing Terrascan as the default IaC code analysis tool for microsoftsecuritydevops@1, then this feature is extremely important.
Terrascan has the GDN_TERRASCAN_USETERRAFORMCACHE to authenticate using the terraform init cache for remote modules.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

"this method does not seem to work within the microsoftsecuritydevops@1 task' - Is there any error in the pipeline debug log? If there is, please share.

I get error:
##[error]2024-07-23 09:24:52,900 [MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Failed to download module terraform.corp.ad.com/azure/mount-secrets/vault:1.1.1
##[error]2024-07-23 09:24:52,976 [MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Failed to download module terraform.corp.ad.com/azure/keyvault/azurerm:4.3.0
Is there no other way to authenticate to a private module registry while using MicrosoftSecurityDevOps?

I'd expect an "unauthorized" error in case of authentication issues. Are there more details logged if you run the pipeline in diagnostics mode?

I just re-ran in diagnostic mode, and it's showing the same error message. That's the error message is would normally show when it failed to authenticate with our Terraform Enterprise


How do you use checkov to access and analyze your Private Terraform Module Registry on your local machine? It would be great if you could share the detailed steps so I can try to help you implement it in the DevOps pipeline. 2. Is your Private Terraform Module Registry an HCP Terraform Private Registry or other Private Registries?


According to this doc Task Environment Variables, this task doesn't have environment variables TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN and TF_HOST_NAME.

We use private HCP registry. I use env variables TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN and TF_HOST_NAME in my local machine and it works.
Exactly, the task it is missing those very important variables.
Terrascan has GDN_TERRASCAN_USETERRAFORMCACHE, which works, but opensource Terrascan has not been updated in years since they were purchased by Tenable, so we are trying to switch to Checkov

Based on the current situation, it's suggested that you use checkov directly in the pipeline and set environment variables in scripts instead of using MicrosoftSecurityDevOps@1 task. You can refer to the scripts in the answer below.

You can try to install checkov in the pipeline and set environment variables in scripts.
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      # Install Checkov
      pip install checkov

      # Set the environment variable
      export TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN=$(TF_REGISTRY_TOKEN)
      export TF_HOST_NAME=$(TF_HOST_NAME)  
      # Run Checkov
      checkov -d . --download-external-modules true -o junitxml > checkov-result.xml 


- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '**/*checkov-result.xml'
    testRunTitle: 'Checkov code scane'


